# Can we automate the app installed on real device via TestFlight?

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-java

can we automate an ios app installed on a real device via TestFlight? or do I need to have the complete source code or .ipa file?

When I tried to check via appium inspector, getting error bundleId not identified?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! You can even automate system applications considering you provide the correct `bundleId` capability value. When you are automating an already installed app you should:

1. Not provide the `app` capability.
2. Provide the `bundleId` capability with the valid bundle ID of the application you are targeting.

Take note that if you are using Appium 2.0, then any non-W3C-compliant [capability](https://appiumpro.com/editions/123-migrating-to-appium-20-part-1-capability-prefixes) should be prefixed with `appium:`. Example: `appium:bundleId`

Comment: able to install IntegrationApp on real device via Xcode. However when I'm trying to access the other installed apps like chrome facing error xcodebuildfailed with code 65 though I've developer certificate added to xcode.

Comment: Xcode build failed with code 65 usually happens when Appium fails installing WebDriverAgent on the device. You can try running `Test` for WebDriverAgent through Xcode. If it build successfully and runs, then you can try cleaning `DerivedData` folder of Xcode and running an Appium session. This is unrelated to the original question though

Comment: what's the ideal approach while working with team, should we have the app installed in device OR have the .ipa file and install when starting appium session OR get the source code and build it using xcode ?

Comment: The problem with WebDriverAgent is that in its essence it is a XCUITest. This means that even if you have the WebDriverAgent.ipa or already installed on the device, you need a way to start it. This is completely unrelated to your original question and there is no point making a discussion in comments. You can find my coordinates in my profile and contact me, I'm happy to give you some pointers on the way I do it